# PTIJ: Are Jews allowed to fight with one another?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The prophet Isaiah said [Is. 2:4]:

> **לֹא־יִשָּׂ֨א ג֤וֹי אֶל־גּוֹי֙ חֶ֔רֶב**
>
> Goy shall not lift up sword against goy.

Are Jews exempted from this injunction?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Against other Jews who misread sources, [definitely](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.21b.1-2?lang=bi). Highly applicable for Purim Torah

Comment: Does this mean that Jews and goyim can fight each other?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. [Shemot 32:27](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemot/32.27#e1n7) states explicitly that G-d demands that we fight with and kill each other!

> וַיֹּ֣אמֶר לָהֶ֗ם כֹּֽה־אָמַ֤ר י״י֙ אֱלֹהֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל שִׂ֥ימוּ אִישׁ־חַרְבּ֖וֹ עַל־יְרֵכ֑וֹ עִבְר֨וּ וָשׁ֜וּבוּ מִשַּׁ֤עַר לָשַׁ֙עַר֙ בַּֽמַּחֲנֶ֔ה וְהִרְג֧וּ אִֽישׁ־אֶת־אָחִ֛יו וְאִ֥ישׁ אֶת־רֵעֵ֖הוּ וְאִ֥ישׁ אֶת־קְרֹבֽוֹ׃
>
> He said to them, “Thus says Hashem, the God of Israel, ‘Every man put his sword on his thigh, and go back and forth from gate to gate throughout the camp, and every man kill his brother, and every man his companion, and every man his neighbor.’”

The reason for this, as explained by the commentaries there, is because once upon a time, the Jews worshiped the Golden Calf.

Comment: +1 Technically correct, the best kind of correct, especially this time of year.

Answer (score 0):

Only when Jews obey God's commandments are they prohibited from using a sword against each other as it says (Vayikra 26:6):

> וְנָתַתִּ֤י שָׁלוֹם֙ בָּאָ֔רֶץ וּשְׁכַבְתֶּ֖ם וְאֵ֣ין מַחֲרִ֑יד
>   וְהִשְׁבַּתִּ֞י חַיָּ֤ה רָעָה֙ מִן־הָאָ֔רֶץ **וְחֶ֖רֶב לֹא־תַעֲבֹ֥ר
>   בְּאַרְצְכֶֽם**

My translation of the bold - " A sword shall not pass in your land."

Of course, there's no way to infer that Jews cannot kill each other without using a sword under these conditions.